# ValidationPipe enableImplicitConversion transforms arrays of objects into array of arrays

Tags: typescript, graphql, nestjs

I'm creating a resolver that takes an input. And inside this input, there is a list of sub-inputs.

```
@InputType()
class MySubInput {
  @Field()
  field0: string;
  @Field()
  field1: string;
}

@InputType()
class MyInput {
  @Field(() => [MySubInput])
  list: MySubInput[];
}

@Resolver(() => MyObject)
export class MyResolver {
  @Query(() => Boolean)
  async myResolver(@Args({ name: 'input', type: () => MyInput }) input: MyInput): Promise<boolean> {
    console.log(input);
    return true;
  }
}
```

I'm also trying to use the `ValidationPipe`, in my `main.ts`:

```
const app = await NestFactory.create(MyModule, { bodyParser: false });
app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe({
  transform: true,
  transformOptions: {
    enableImplicitConversion: true, // <- This line.
  },
}));
```

And here is my query:

```
query q($input: MyInput!) {
    myResolver (input: $input)
}
```

```json
{
  "input": {
    "list": [
      {
        "field0": "field0_0",
        "field1": "field1_0"
      },
      {
        "field0": "field0_1",
        "field1": "field1_1"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

If I don't activate `enableImplicitConversion: true`, then I got a proper input at runtime:

```
MyInput {
  list: [
    { field0: 'field0_0', field1: 'field1_0' },
    { field0: 'field0_1', field1: 'field1_1' }
  ]
}
```

[image]

But when I activate it, I don't get objects (`{}`) inside `list` but arrays with a property `field0` and `field1`:

```
MyInput {
  list: [
    [ field0: 'field0_0', field1: 'field1_0' ],
    [ field0: 'field0_1', field1: 'field1_1' ]
  ]
}
```

[image]

---

Is there a reason for that, what is happening? How can I prevent it?